# Linux: bat cache --build says "unexpected argument '--build' found"

Tags: linux

This question is about "bat", the "cat" replacement with sysntax coloring, **not** about Windows .bat files.

According to the README on [bat's GitHub page](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat#adding-new-syntaxes--language-definitions) as well as the man page, I should run `bat cache --build` when I want to add a new syntax definition. But when I do so, I get this error:

> `error: unexpected argument '--build' found`.

Trying just `bat cache` says

> [bat error]: 'cache': No such file or directory (os error 2)

but unfortunately it does not specify which file it expected to find. My assumption is that it has problems creating the cache for the first time.

Comment: Yes, I've created `~/.config/bat/syntaxes` and put a syntax file there.

Answer (score 1):

- Is your version of `bat` up to date?
- Does `bat --help` mention that you can use `bat cache`?
- Does a file named `cache` exist in the current directory? If yes, try to cd to a different directory.

Expected result:

```
[deuterium ~]$ wget 'https://github.com/sharkdp/bat/releases/download/v0.23.0/bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz'

[deuterium ~]$ tar xvf bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.tar.gz

[deuterium ~]$ cd bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/

[deuterium ~/bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]$ ./bat --help
A cat(1) clone with syntax highlighting and Git integration.

Usage: bat [OPTIONS] [FILE]...
       bat <COMMAND>

Arguments:
  [FILE]...
          File(s) to print / concatenate. Use a dash ('-') or no argument at all to read from
          standard input.

Options:
  -A, --show-all
          Show non-printable characters like space, tab or newline. This option can also be used to
          print binary files. Use '--tabs' to control the width of the tab-placeholders.

      --nonprintable-notation <notation>
          Set notation for non-printable characters.

          Possible values:
            * unicode (␇, ␊, ␀, ..)
            * caret   (^G, ^J, ^@, ..)

  -p, --plain...
          Only show plain style, no decorations. This is an alias for '--style=plain'. When '-p' is
          used twice ('-pp'), it also disables automatic paging (alias for '--style=plain
          --paging=never').

  -l, --language <language>
          Explicitly set the language for syntax highlighting. The language can be specified as a
          name (like 'C++' or 'LaTeX') or possible file extension (like 'cpp', 'hpp' or 'md'). Use
          '--list-languages' to show all supported language names and file extensions.

  -H, --highlight-line <N:M>
          Highlight the specified line ranges with a different background color For example:
            '--highlight-line 40' highlights line 40
            '--highlight-line 30:40' highlights lines 30 to 40
            '--highlight-line :40' highlights lines 1 to 40
            '--highlight-line 40:' highlights lines 40 to the end of the file
            '--highlight-line 30:+10' highlights lines 30 to 40

      --file-name <name>
          Specify the name to display for a file. Useful when piping data to bat from STDIN when bat
          does not otherwise know the filename. Note that the provided file name is also used for
          syntax detection.

  -d, --diff
          Only show lines that have been added/removed/modified with respect to the Git index. Use
          --diff-context=N to control how much context you want to see.

      --diff-context <N>
          Include N lines of context around added/removed/modified lines when using '--diff'.

      --tabs <T>
          Set the tab width to T spaces. Use a width of 0 to pass tabs through directly

      --wrap <mode>
          Specify the text-wrapping mode (*auto*, never, character). The '--terminal-width' option
          can be used in addition to control the output width.

  -S, --chop-long-lines
          Truncate all lines longer than screen width. Alias for '--wrap=never'.

      --terminal-width <width>
          Explicitly set the width of the terminal instead of determining it automatically. If
          prefixed with '+' or '-', the value will be treated as an offset to the actual terminal
          width. See also: '--wrap'.

  -n, --number
          Only show line numbers, no other decorations. This is an alias for '--style=numbers'

      --color <when>
          Specify when to use colored output. The automatic mode only enables colors if an
          interactive terminal is detected - colors are automatically disabled if the output goes to
          a pipe.
          Possible values: *auto*, never, always.

      --italic-text <when>
          Specify when to use ANSI sequences for italic text in the output. Possible values: always,
          *never*.

      --decorations <when>
          Specify when to use the decorations that have been specified via '--style'. The automatic
          mode only enables decorations if an interactive terminal is detected. Possible values:
          *auto*, never, always.

  -f, --force-colorization
          Alias for '--decorations=always --color=always'. This is useful if the output of bat is
          piped to another program, but you want to keep the colorization/decorations.

      --paging <when>
          Specify when to use the pager. To disable the pager, use --paging=never' or its
          alias,'-P'. To disable the pager permanently, set BAT_PAGER to an empty string. To control
          which pager is used, see the '--pager' option. Possible values: *auto*, never, always.

      --pager <command>
          Determine which pager is used. This option will override the PAGER and BAT_PAGER
          environment variables. The default pager is 'less'. To control when the pager is used, see
          the '--paging' option. Example: '--pager "less -RF"'.

  -m, --map-syntax <glob:syntax>
          Map a glob pattern to an existing syntax name. The glob pattern is matched on the full
          path and the filename. For example, to highlight *.build files with the Python syntax, use
          -m '*.build:Python'. To highlight files named '.myignore' with the Git Ignore syntax, use
          -m '.myignore:Git Ignore'. Note that the right-hand side is the *name* of the syntax, not
          a file extension.

      --ignored-suffix <ignored-suffix>
          Ignore extension. For example:
            'bat --ignored-suffix ".dev" my_file.json.dev' will use JSON syntax, and ignore '.dev'

      --theme <theme>
          Set the theme for syntax highlighting. Use '--list-themes' to see all available themes. To
          set a default theme, add the '--theme="..."' option to the configuration file or export
          the BAT_THEME environment variable (e.g.: export BAT_THEME="...").

      --list-themes
          Display a list of supported themes for syntax highlighting.

      --style <components>
          Configure which elements (line numbers, file headers, grid borders, Git modifications, ..)
          to display in addition to the file contents. The argument is a comma-separated list of
          components to display (e.g. 'numbers,changes,grid') or a pre-defined style ('full'). To
          set a default style, add the '--style=".."' option to the configuration file or export the
          BAT_STYLE environment variable (e.g.: export BAT_STYLE="..").

          Possible values:

            * default: enables recommended style components (default).
            * full: enables all available components.
            * auto: same as 'default', unless the output is piped.
            * plain: disables all available components.
            * changes: show Git modification markers.
            * header: alias for 'header-filename'.
            * header-filename: show filenames before the content.
            * header-filesize: show file sizes before the content.
            * grid: vertical/horizontal lines to separate side bar
                    and the header from the content.
            * rule: horizontal lines to delimit files.
            * numbers: show line numbers in the side bar.
            * snip: draw separation lines between distinct line ranges.

  -r, --line-range <N:M>
          Only print the specified range of lines for each file. For example:
            '--line-range 30:40' prints lines 30 to 40
            '--line-range :40' prints lines 1 to 40
            '--line-range 40:' prints lines 40 to the end of the file
            '--line-range 40' only prints line 40
            '--line-range 30:+10' prints lines 30 to 40

  -L, --list-languages
          Display a list of supported languages for syntax highlighting.

  -u, --unbuffered
          This option exists for POSIX-compliance reasons ('u' is for 'unbuffered'). The output is
          always unbuffered - this option is simply ignored.

      --diagnostic
          Show diagnostic information for bug reports.

      --acknowledgements
          Show acknowledgements.

  -h, --help
          Print help (see a summary with '-h')

  -V, --version
          Print version

You can use 'bat cache' to customize syntaxes and themes. See 'bat cache --help' for more
information

[deuterium ~/bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]$ ./bat cache --help
Modify the syntax-definition and theme cache

Usage: bat cache [OPTIONS] <--build|--clear>

Options:
  -b, --build
          Initialize (or update) the syntax/theme cache by loading from the source directory
          (default: the configuration directory).

  -c, --clear
          Remove the cached syntax definitions and themes.

      --source <dir>
          Use a different directory to load syntaxes and themes from.

      --target <dir>
          Use a different directory to store the cached syntax and theme set.

      --blank
          Create completely new syntax and theme sets (instead of appending to the default sets).

      --acknowledgements
          Build acknowledgements.bin.

  -h, --help
          Print help (see a summary with '-h')

[deuterium ~/bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]$ ./bat cache --build
No themes were found in '/home/user/.config/bat/themes', using the default set
No syntaxes were found in '/home/user/.config/bat/syntaxes', using the default set.
Writing theme set to /home/user/.cache/bat/themes.bin ... okay
Writing syntax set to /home/user/.cache/bat/syntaxes.bin ... okay
Writing metadata to folder /home/user/.cache/bat ... okay

[deuterium ~/bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]$ ./bat --version
bat 0.23.0 (871abd2)

[deuterium ~/bat-v0.23.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]$ ./bat foo
[bat error]: 'foo': No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

It should work without creating ~/.config/bat in advance.